# More efficient Google Drive sync app for Android

Tags: android, file-synchronization, google-drive

I want to synchronise files between Google Drive and my Android phone.

[FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) does that, but in a very inefficient way: It runs on a schedule (or when triggered manually or via Tasker/MacroDroid/…) and then checks every single file every single time. If I run it on any kind of schedule that doesn't make me wait way too long for any changes to get transmitted, then it's consistently the biggest battery drain on my phone, because it checks 2×24000 files 1-2 times per hour. These syncs usually take over 20 minutes, even without any changes.

On my laptop I'm using [InSync](https://www.insynchq.com), which does pretty much nothing until there is an actual change. For the Google Drive side, getting notified of changes seems to be a feature that just works, for the local side, this might have some requirement of the file system and/or operating system. But since Android is Linux-based, I assume this should be something I can set up somewhat easily.
I have even considered setting up a small Arch system inside [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) and running InSync in that, but the tutorial I tried didn't work for me and running basically three systems inside each other all the time doesn't sound too efficient either.

"[Autosync for Google Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.drivesync)" claims to do what I want, but since the free version only works for files up to 10MB, I cannot test it before paying.

The description of "[GDriveSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yottajoy.gdrive)" talks about schedules, so it probably works the same way as FolderSync. The same applies to "[Sync & Comparison](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.prcj.drivesync)" and "[Drive Syncrypt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.semaphore.drivesyncrypt)".

Is there a proper InSync equivalent for Android (for which I don't have to blindly pay and hope that it works)?

Comment: Folder sync has this option in advanced settings, did you try **enabling**  that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn7yS.png

Comment: That sounds like it would never sync a cloud deletion to my phone. But I want it to do that.

Comment: I don't think so. Enable sync deletions in basic settings menu and as above in advanced. I haven't tried out what I am suggesting because my sync needs are different but give it a spin - you already have a 20 min benchmark to compare with